# Compress numbers in a string array (#3, #1, #2, #4) to range (#1:#4)

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

1.
I've made a function that takes a string array,

```
{"foo", "#123", "#124", "bar", "#125", "#126"}
```

makes a new array with the numbers converted to a range:

```
{"foo", "#123:126", "bar"}
```

and returns:

```
"foo,#123:126,bar"
```

2. Note it doesn't change ranges of just two numbers (it shouldn't change `{"#1", "#2"}` to `{"#1:#2"}`). This is because `#1:#2` and `#1,#2` occupy the same size.
3. Order is important for all values excluding those that are squished in a range. For example, in `{#6, #5, #1, foo, #2, #3}`, `#2` and `#3` will be squished with `#1`, that's okay but the rest should have the same order.

Below is my implementation, it is very time inefficient because of the multiple `.Contains` calls.

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ids = new string[] {
            "foo", //output: unmodified
            "#60", "#59", "#61", "#62", //from integer is in between, output: #59:#62
            "#12", "#14", "#17", "#13", "#18", "#bar", "#19", "#20", //two ranges and string intertwined, output: #12:#14,#17:#20,#bar
            "#25", "#26", //output: unmodified
            "#39", "#38", //output: unmodified
            "baz", //output: unmodified
            "#12", "#13", "#14" //duplicate sequences, output: #12:#14
        };
        //this is what the function should output when fed `ids`:
        Console.WriteLine("foo,#59:#62,#12:#14,#17:#20,#bar,#25,#26,#38,#39,baz,#12:#14");
        Console.WriteLine(Compress(ids));
        Console.Read();
    }
    static string Compress(IEnumerable<string> IDs)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var ignore = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var item in IDs)
        {
            if (ignore.Contains(item)) continue;
            var id = item;
            if (id.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                int fromInt;
                if (int.TryParse(id.Substring(1), out fromInt))
                {
                    var less1 = $"#{fromInt - 1}";
                    var plus1 = $"#{fromInt + 1}";
                    var hasPlus1 = IDs.Contains(plus1);
                    if (IDs.Contains(less1) && hasPlus1) continue;
                    var plus2 = $"#{fromInt + 2}";
                    if (hasPlus1 && IDs.Contains(plus2))
                    {
                        ignore.Add(plus1);
                        ignore.Add(plus2);
                        var toInt = fromInt + 2;
                        while (IDs.Contains($"#{toInt + 1}"))
                        {
                            toInt += 1;
                            ignore.Add($"#{toInt}");
                        }
                        id = $"#{fromInt}:#{toInt}";
                    }
                }
            }
            result.Add(id);
        }
        return string.Join(",", result);
    }
}
```

---

Can anyone tell me how can I make it more efficient?

Comment: How about you just put all the numbered #'s aside, sort them in O(nlgn) and loop through in O(n) to generate the final result in a quite straightforward fashion?

Comment: @Elmo You can't really say that ordered is preserved in the first example you showed, as `126` is now before `bar` when it used to be after it.

Comment: So preserving order is important but the fact that 125 and 126 comes after bar isn't?

Comment: And anyways, you can still sort them aside, make the ranges list, and then go through the array only once, until you find a number the belongs to a range, then you put the range instead of it and remove any number in the range afterwards.

Comment: No, that's just a test case. In real world scenario, the numerical ranges can be squished together.

Comment: @Elmo I gave an answer below, but I realized I don't understand the 3rd comment in your code.  Can you explain how it ends up with two ranges?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Because it doesn't have #15 and #16

Comment: @Elmo I see, will edit.

Comment: Define preserver order in the question

Comment: So, if I read my crystal ball correctly, you want to preserve the order of any non-numeric entry, but between non-numeric entries the order does not matter?

Comment: Your definition is non-sensical. `"#12", "#14", "#17", "#13"` should not be allowed to become `#12:#14,#17` because it changes the order between `#13` and `#17` and `#17` is not part of the sequence. Or, the order is allowed to change, but then any value can just look ahead through the entire array to see if it finds its next number and pull that number all the way back to where it is.

Comment: @MicroVirus I think I don't understand what you're trying to say here. Real-world scenario has the numbers in the range sorted, like  #60,#17,#12,#13,#14,#19. I just added that condition as an edge-case. I know it'll be more efficient if you don't include that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing this (comments in the code below):

```
static string Compress(IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
    var list = new LinkedList<string>(ids);

    // store the numbers and their linked-list nodes
    var dict = new Dictionary<LinkedListNode<string>, int>();
    var current = list.First;
    int num;
    while(current != null)
    {
        var value = current.Value;
        if(value.StartsWith("#") && int.TryParse(value.TrimStart('#'), out num)) 
            dict[current] = num;

        current = current.Next;
    }

    // if found more than 2 numbers, compress to a range
    if(dict.Count > 2)
    {
        var sorted = dict.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToArray();
        var ranges = new List<Range>();
        int min, max;
        for(var i = 0; i < sorted.Length;)
        {
            var rangeNodes = new List<LinkedListNode<string>>();
            min = max = sorted[i].Value;

            // record nodes, until we can't find a continuing number
            // (Note: this loop operates on the same counter as the outer
            // for-loop, so we only iterate through the sorted list once)
            for(; i < sorted.Length && sorted[i].Value - max <= 1; i++)
            {
                rangeNodes.Add(sorted[i].Key);
                max = sorted[i].Value;
            }

            // if more than 2 numbers, replace the first string, and remove the others 
            if(rangeNodes.Count > 2)
            {
                rangeNodes[0].Value = string.Format("#{0}:#{1}", min, max);
                for(int n = 1; n < rangeNodes.Count; n++)
                    list.Remove(rangeNodes[n]);
            }   
        }
    }

    // create a joined string
    return string.Join(",",list);
}
```

Comment: I think the requirement is contiguous numbers

Comment: @Frisbee not sure... The example says `{"foo", "#123", "#124", "bar", "#125", "#126"}` turns into `"foo,#123:126,bar"`.

Comment: Yes and that is contiguous.  The existing code checks for +1 -1.  You code  does not check for contiguous.

Comment: @Elmo editted. slightly more complicated, but should fulfill the requirements.

Comment: The last `foreach` looks like `O(n^3)` worst-case time though.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek edited. I guess using a linked list simplifies things in this case since we're likely to do a lot of removals.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I'm afraid the complexity is unchanged. You iterate over `O(n)` sorted numbers, each acquiring up to `n/3 = O(n)` range nodes and then deleting them from the list of all inputs, which is `O(n)` elements long so a search in it will have `O(n)` complexity (although the remove is `O(1)` now). So `O(n)` numbers * `O(n)` nodes to delete * `O(n)` length of the list still gives `O(n^3)`

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek unless I'm missing something... it's O(n) for the ranges, and O(n) for the removals, so should be O(n^2), no?  note that the nested for loops operate on the same counter (i), so it's really a single loop.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Yeah, that's true, the `sorted`/`rangeNodes` loop would be `O(n)` and not `O(n^2)`. Sorry I didn't notice. Good job on that one!

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Thank you. I added a note to clarify that point.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a two pass algorithm. The main challenge was to pick the right data structure supporting fast key lookup and duplicate keys. `Dictionary<int, List<int>` looks too space consuming, so I decided to use a linked list like structure consisting of a `Dictionary<int, int>` holding the first key position, and a separate array with links plus processing information.

The first pass prepares the processing structures, and the second emits the result. Since every element is resolved only once (including range checks using the dictionary lookups with O(1) time complexity), the time complexity of the algorithm IMO should be O(N).

Other than that, it's very similar to yours, hence might be considered as optimized implementation.

```
enum EntryType { Single, Range, Unknown }

struct Entry
{
    public string Value;
    public int Number;
    public int Next; // position of the next value with the same number
    public EntryType Type;
}

static string Compress(IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    var entryList = input.Select(value => new Entry { Value = value }).ToArray();
    var numberQueue = new Dictionary<int, int>(entryList.Length); // Key=number, Value=position
    for (int pos = entryList.Length - 1; pos >= 0; pos--)
    {
        var value = entryList[pos].Value;
        int number;
        if (value.Length > 1 && value[0] == '#' && int.TryParse(value.Substring(1), out number))
        {
            int nextPos;
            if (!numberQueue.TryGetValue(number, out nextPos)) nextPos = -1;
            entryList[pos].Number = number;
            entryList[pos].Type = EntryType.Unknown;
            entryList[pos].Next = nextPos;
            numberQueue[number] = pos;
        }
    }
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int pos = 0; pos < entryList.Length; pos++)
    {
        var entryType = entryList[pos].Type;
        if (entryType == EntryType.Range) continue; // already processed
        var number = entryList[pos].Number;
        int startPos = pos, endPos = pos, prevCount = 0, nextCount = 0;
        if (entryType == EntryType.Unknown)
        {
            for (int prevPos; numberQueue.TryGetValue(number - prevCount - 1, out prevPos) && prevPos >= 0; startPos = prevPos, prevCount++) { }
            for (int nextPos; numberQueue.TryGetValue(number + nextCount + 1, out nextPos) && nextPos >= 0; endPos = nextPos, nextCount++) { }
            entryType = prevCount + nextCount >= 2 ? EntryType.Range : EntryType.Single;
            for (int offset = -prevCount; offset <= nextCount; offset++)
            {
                var nextNumber = number + offset;
                int nextPos = numberQueue[nextNumber];
                entryList[nextPos].Type = entryType;
                numberQueue[nextNumber] = entryList[nextPos].Next;
            }
        }
        if (output.Length > 0) output.Append(',');
        if (entryType == EntryType.Single)
            output.Append(entryList[pos].Value);
        else
            output.Append(entryList[startPos].Value).Append(':').Append(entryList[endPos].Value);
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```